# How to make moving car on the limiting mask?

Tags: c#, xna, desktop, collision

I want to make some race game. Game is 2D with the view from the top. I need mask that must limit a road for adequately work of moving car :)
I have tried per pixel collision but it's not good idea because Scan for collision happen always that process very load CPU.
I guess i need something method that will can calculate once and next time use calculated without tension.

What do you suggest to me?
I have C# with Xna Game Studio.
Excuse me for my English:)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @tnw He has tried per pixel collision as is stated in the question.

Comment: @user3752919 You should read on XNA collisions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb313876.aspx) and then ask specific programming related problems you encounter here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain you how would i go to solve problem. if you road looks like on image, you can use pixel collsion only for part of texture (blue circle) no need to check whole image. And then you check collsions only on edges (protruding parts) of car tiny green circles.

[image]

other way could be that you draw road using vectors (to create a polygon). then you can check if your car intersects iiner and outer polygon. all between those two polygons are road.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear to me. But just to post my general approach on collision detection if i dont know the programming language; here you go:

```
    // fill in the collision map, marking 'R' in the spots where the road is and ' ' where driving is allowed, make the arrays larger to get more detail
    private char[,] strCollisionMap = {
                                            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                            {' ', ' ', 'R', 'R', ' ' },
                                            {' ', 'R', ' ', ' ', 'R' },
                                            {'R', ' ', ' ', 'R', ' ' },
                                            {'R', ' ', 'R', ' ', ' ' },
                                            {' ', 'R', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' }
                                      };
    private bool IsCarOnTheRoad(float carX, float carY, int screenWidth, int screenHeight)
    {
        int h = strCollisionMap.GetLength(0);
        int w = strCollisionMap.GetLength(1);

        float fH = screenHeight / h;
        float fW = screenWidth / w;


        int nX = (int)Math.Round(carX / fW);
        int nY = (int)Math.Round(carY / fH);
        if (strCollisionMap[nX, nY] == 'R')
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: If its unclear, why answer? This may answer the question (for a grid based game) and it may not. We simply don't have enough information to know.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I liked the idea of helping someone who usually gets shot down because of his/her (terrible) grammar or programming skills. But you're still totally right, shouldn't have done that ;)

Comment: I have no problem helping people (I've answered many "undeserving" questions for that reason). This one is just so unclear I don't think there *is* an answer yet.